# I want to use parent directory‘s parent directory

Tags: java, directory

I am making a Java program and I want use parent directory’s parent directory， as I want to change the content of a file which is in that directory.

So far I tried :

```
static File pdir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getParentFile();
static File pdir2 = new File(System.getProperty("pdir")).getParentFile();
```

and some other things like that but none of them worked.

Error, on the second line, was:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at Plugin.main.main(main.java:20) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.base/java.io.File.(File.java:278) at Plugin.pfun.(pfun.java:13) ... 1 more

Can you recommend anything?

Comment: Define "none of them worked". Did the code compile? Were you getting any errors or exceptions?

Comment: no, sometimes it gave an error and sometimes it worked incompletely, it gave an error in the code I wrote and error is" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at Plugin.main.main(main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:278)
 at Plugin.pfun.<clinit>(pfun.java:13)
 ... 1 more"

Comment: Check if `System.getProperty` actually returns the value you think it does. It seems to me that in one of the cases it returns a `null` which is then passed to constructor of `File` which isn't happy about that.

Comment: when I try write only the first line , it works . if I write the second line as well , it gives the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second line to

```
static File pdir2 = pdir.getParentFile();
```

Comment: Happy to help. Consider accepting my answer if replied to your question.